# Send data to all subscribers elements with observable - angular2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, observable

I want to send data to my all elements called 'modal', but only one of them reciving message.

I have a service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ModalService {

private _isOpen = new Subject();
isOpen$ = this._isOpen.asObservable();

open(id: string) {
    this._isOpen.next({isOpen: true, id: id});
}

close(id: string) {
    this._isOpen.next({isOpen: false, id: id});
}
```

and component:

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

import {ModalService} from './modal.service';


@Component({
     selector: 'modal',
     template: `
     <ng-content></ng-content>`,
     styleUrls: ['app/workshop/modal.component.css'],
     providers: [ModalService],

})

export class ModalComponent {

@Input() ID;

private show = false;

constructor(private _modal: ModalService) {

    this._modal.isOpen$.subscribe(
        (value) => {
            console.log(value)
            if(this.ID === value.id) {
                this.show = value.isOpen;
            }
        }
    );

}

open() {
    this._modal.open(this.ID);
}

close() {
    this._modal.close(this.ID);
}

}
```

All works fine but the problem appear when i want inject service in any else Component and send message to rest of subscribers. I don't know how i can share message for all elements type of 'modal'. I can hook DOM element but i have problem with Component. How i can hook a all 'modal' elements to observable?

Thanks for help

Comment: Where do you provide `ModalService`? Every component where you inject it or only once globally (`bootstrap()` or root component)?

Comment: I edit my post (Component code). I inject service in every component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you need to share the same instance to all these components. To do that, set the service in the `providers` attribute of the main component:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  providers: [ ModalService ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  (...)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i don't join headers to code. I added this now.

Comment: I think that you should remove the `ModalService` from providers of the `ModalComponent` component and move it to the main component only. Right now you have one instance of the service per modal component instance...